# c# testing a generic exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, xunit

I'm writing integration test for a repository class that operates on a `MySQL` database.

I want to test the fact that inserting the same record two times throw an exception, I'm using `xUnit`

```
    [Fact]
    public void Insert_SamePaymentTwoTimes_ThrowInvalidOperationException()
    {
        Payment payment;
        using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
        {
            int? id = 0;
            id = paymentRepository.Insert(testPayment);
            payment = paymentRepository.GetById(id);

            Assert.Throws<MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException>(() => paymentRepository.Insert(payment));
        }
    }
```

The test works fine but I want my tests to be as generic as possibile, if later my `PaymentRepository` writes to let's say `MSSQL` the test will fail.

I came up with this solution :

Change `Insert()` function so it throw a generic system exception:

```
using (var conn = GetOpenConnection())
{
   try
   {
       paymentId = conn.Insert(paymentData);
   }
   catch (MySqlException ex)
   {
       throw new InvalidOperationException(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

and catch that exception on my test:

```
    [Fact]
    public void Insert_SamePaymentTwoTimes_ThrowInvalidOperationException()
    {
        Payment payment;
        using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
        {
            int? id = 0;
            id = paymentRepository.Insert(testPayment);
            payment = paymentRepository.GetById(id);

            Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(() => paymentRepository.Insert(payment));
        }
    }
```

Are there any alternatives to this approach ? I was thinking of maybe implement a custom `DbException` in order to be as generic as possibile.

Comment: `DbException` would make a lot more sense than `InvalidOperationException`. Unless you're trying to hide the source of the exception, remember to initialize the new exception with the source exception object - otherwise you destroy the stack trace.

Comment: You don't need a custom `DbException` because that [already exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbexception).

Comment: That's good to know, but how do I make it work ?

Comment: 1. In your test, replace `InvalidOperationException` with `DbException`. 2. ??? 3. Profit! You don't need to catch or rethrow anything either; all ADO.NET database exceptions derive from `DbException`, regardless of what provider you're using.

Comment: It doesn't work, my test fail with this: Assert.Throws() Failure
    Expected: typeof(System.Data.Common.DbException)
    Actual:   typeof(MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException):